# When I import a photo into PS CC 2018 I have a colored background, Im not sure what setting I have messed up

Tags: adobe-photoshop

The yellow in the background happens around photos as background with any photos I import. What do I do to fix my settings to be a transparent background when importing?

[image]

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GDSE! It's hard to tell what's going on since your screenshot only shows the image itself and it's very small. I can see some kind of light rectangle in the left side, but I don't understand what it is. Maybe you could show us the layers panel? Also i don't understand what you mean by "importing" an image into Photoshop. Do you just mean "open"? The background could be part of your document or it could be the background of Photoshop itself.

Comment: Thank you, for your reply. Scott fixed it, I inadvertently changed the pasteboard from transparent to mustard yellow.

Answer (score 1):

You may have mistakenly clicked the pasteboard and inadvertently set a custom color at some point. Which would change the pasteboard to a color.

Merely Right-Click/Control-Click the pasteboard and pick a grey to reset it.

[image]

Comment: That works, can I make it transparent? Instead of grey?

Comment: No. The pasteboard is always present. It's not actually part of any image. The pasteboard is separate from the canvas and it can not be transparent.

Comment: If it was "transparent" what would be revealed behind? :-)